# Kendo UI Mobile - switch tabs after viewing scheduler

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-scheduler

Fellas, I am struggling with the Kendo UI scheduler. After I switch to the tab, I cannot normally go back without it changing the style

```
<div data-role="view" data-init="initScheduler" id="scheduler" data-title="Scheduler">
    <header data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <a data-role="button" href="#home" data-icon="back" data-align="left" ></a>
            <span data-role="view-title">iOS Platform</span>
            <a data-role="button" data-rel="drawer" href="#right-drawer" data-icon="share" data-align="right" ></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="scheduler"></div>
</div>
```

That's how I call the scheduler and the problem is demonstrated on this page http://chris1904.webege.com/ 
If you go to scheduler, you realize that if you go back the UI looks different. How can I prevent it from doing that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate IDs on your View and your Scheduler and your Scheduler gets initialized on the View instead on the intended container.